# Cant visit some websites in linux but in windows XP I can

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I have a Ubuntu box and a windowsXP box, both are working well.
But I can't visit some websites(like Apple.com, www.suning.com) in Ubuntu while I can with my other windows box.
Those are just ordinary sites, and I haven't modified hosts files in both boxes for them.
I suppose this has to with dns and stuff, but how to fix it?

There is only one valid line of "nameserver 192.168.1.1" in /etc/resolv.conf.
When I ping www.suning.com in Ubuntu, it says:
`64 bytes from www.suning.com(202.106.195.30):icmp_req=4 ttl=236 time=55.4 ms`
But when I do this in windows it says:
`Reply from 123.103.65.243: bytes=32 time=47ms TTL=42`
Apparently the IP Ubuntu resolved is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that might not be the best example, since that address resolves to different ASNs all over China:

```
<me>@harley:~$ whois -h whois.cymru.com " -v 61.147.122.75"
AS      | IP               | BGP Prefix          | CC | Registry | Allocated  | AS Name
23650   | 61.147.122.75    | 61.147.122.0/24     | CN | apnic    | 2000-03-14 | CHINANET-JS-AS-AP AS Number for CHINANET jiangsu province backbone
<me>@harley:~$ whois -h whois.cymru.com " -v 202.106.195.30"
AS      | IP               | BGP Prefix          | CC | Registry | Allocated  | AS Name
4808    | 202.106.195.30   | 202.106.192.0/19    | CN | apnic    | 1998-08-17 | CHINA169-BJ CNCGROUP IP network China169 Beijing Province Network
<me>@harley:~$ whois -h whois.cymru.com " -v 123.103.65.243"
AS      | IP               | BGP Prefix          | CC | Registry | Allocated  | AS Name
17431   | 123.103.65.243   | 123.103.64.0/19     | CN | apnic    | 2006-12-06 | TONET Beijing TONEK Information Technology Development Company
```

However, you've just demonstrated that your boxes are both resolving DNS just fine via your router, which is on address `192.168.1.1`.

At this point, I would change the DNS servers that the router is using, if you have the luxury of doing so. `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` are good candidates, as they're Google's public DNS servers. For the Linux box, you can use `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to do this, as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the HTTP connection and raw messages with telnet.

```
% telnet www.suning.com 80
```

the host response if connected with HTTP:

```
Trying 183.60.136.29...
Connected to www.suning.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

next, type HTTP request in interapt:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.suning.com
```

and hit the enter key twice.

networking and connection is succeeded if got the document in the web site. thus, the problem is not system configuration. check your browser setting.